# Search page to search from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a basic search page to search for Employee's skill.

There is a bridge table between dbo.Emp and dbo.Skill table called 'Dbo.Emp_skill_Bridge'.

This is what I have done so far that allows to search only the bridge table.

Example: I need to type in "2" to get Employee's details and only from this table. I have Skill to be typed like "java" and get list of employees from Emp table.

```
dbo.Emp_Skill_Bridge
SkillID (FK) | EmpID (FK)

dbo.Skills
SkillName | SkillID(PK)

dbo.Emp
EmpID (PK) | Fname| LName | .....
```

So I need to search for skills from Skills and get precise Employees' details.
***Updated:***

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String var2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KKSTechConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(var2);

            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Emp_Skill_Bridge where SkillID like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ", con);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Emp_Skill_Bridge ESB INNER JOIN Emp E ON E.EmpId = ESB.EmpId INNER JOIN Skills S ON S.SkillID = ESB.SkillID WHERE ESB.SkillID LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' OR ESB.SkillID LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);


            //string val = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Emp");
            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close(); 
        }
```

The code is working but not the GridView is not showing the data..

Comment: as far as i understood, you have textbox and when you enter numeric values (like 2 ,3...) , search is carried away based on some ID from Emp  table and when "java" is entered it should search from Emp_Skill_Bridge table, is it so ?

Comment: Ur close enough.. With my first code, all I can do is, search using numeric values like (2,3..).. But I want user to type in Java, asp.net and so on.. I have only on textbox and one btn_Search control..

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding you correctly, you can join the two tables and write a query that has an OR keyword that compares the user input with skill and id columns in the WHERE condition

```
SELECT * FROM Emp_skill_Bridge ESB
INNER JOIN Emp E
ON E.Id = ESB.Id
INNER JOIN Skill S
ON S.Id = ESB.SkillId
WHERE SkillID LIKE '% + TextBox1.Text + %' 
OR SkillID LIKE '% + TextBox1.Text + %'
```

I tried to improvise without having the database structure but something like the above work should work. you might have to tweak it a little because I didn't test it.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that? Any possible way where you can show me few codes? Would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: This looks real good, but in ADO.NET connection I'm confused how to implement this..

Comment: '% + TextBox1.Text + %' this part will be a parameter @userInput and then you will send the command with the "addParameterWithValue" value being the TextBox1.Text

Comment: if the code is working and the grid isn't showing the data you should first check whether the dataset is not empty, then make sure the grid has corresponding columns with the right databound values

Comment: I am filling data as `da.Fill(ds, "Emp");` How do I check whether dataset if not empty? Sorry for this but I'm a novice :(

Comment: before you set the datasource for the grid, check if ds is null or not

Comment: @Mutu.. I did this way yet not populated into my Dataset.. No errors as well..

 `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    da.Fill(ds, "Emp");
                    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    con.Close(); 
                }


            }
          }`

Comment: check if your query is returning results by using breakpoints

Comment: I checked.. `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` is showing NULL.. But `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is executing the command.. What do I do now?

Comment: run the query in sql server and make sure it returns results. if not you are going to have to tweak it a little bit

Comment: Its working in SQL Server for me when I executed this way..
`SELECT * FROM Emp_Skill_Bridge ESB 
INNER JOIN Emp E ON E.EmpId = ESB.EmpId 
INNER JOIN Skills S ON S.SkillID = ESB.SkillID 
WHERE ESB.SkillID LIKE '2' OR S.SkillID LIKE 'Java';`

Comment: then you must be passing the parameter incorrectly to the sql command.

Comment: This is how I have done..
` cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();` 
ds is showing NULL when I debugged :(

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Emp_Skill_Bridge");
            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();` 


But its not working.. not able to find the little silly error.. :(

Comment: you don't need the executenonquery, just look at the adapter overleads and give it the connection and the command when initializing it then simply run the da.Fill method that automatically runs the command

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly

```
 //From this query you will get the skill ID
select * from Emp_Skill_Bridge where SkillID like '% + TextBox1.Text +"%' "
//save the result of this query in a variable and pass it to the below query. Example I save the skill iD in a variable myskillid.

//To get the employee you have to pass teh skillID in the employee table, you have to write   another query
select * from Emp where skillID = myskillId

 //It is better to write a store procedure and use them in your code
 Create procedure getskill 
 @skill bigint -- change it to your column's type
 AS
    Declare @skillid bigint -- change it to your column's type
    set @skillid = ( select * from Emp_Skill_Bridge where SkillID like '%' + skillid +'%'  );
    select * from Emp where skillID = @skillid

  // and in your code you have to make the following changes
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = getskill; // procedure name
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Connection = con; // give the connection object
        con.Open(); // open the connection

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Comment: Just one doubt.. SkillID is a INT type which is in Emp_Skill_Bridge.. But Skill column is in dbo.Skills and employee's details in dbo.Emp.. 
Please check my edit on my question to see the DB design..

Comment: @Girish so you can pass your skill id to Emp_Skill_Bridge table and can get the empID and then you have to pass it to emp table. why you are making your design so complex ? just add the skill ID in the dbo.Emp table will solve the problem

Comment: @WaqarJanjua you can't add skillID to the Emp table because one employee can have more than one skill. how do you suppose to deal with an employee that has 5 skills?

Comment: @MutuYolbulan hmm understand. well Grish has shown the db design now, I had just assumed and write the code, I will update it soon.

Answer (score 0):

we have Int.Parse Method , which will return **true** when the provided string can be parsed to int and **false** when it can't.

so when you need to check whether the enter value in the textbox is string or numeric
if its number search based upon the **SkillID** column or if its string search based upon column **SkillName** .

```
string strcommand = string.Empty;
int num;
bool result = int.TryParse(txtboxsearch.Text, out num);
if (result == true)
{
strcommand = "SELECT * FROM Emp_Skill_Bridge ESB INNER JOIN  Emp E ON "+
          "E.EmpId = ESB.EmpId INNER JOIN  Skills S ON " +
          "S.SkillID = ESB.SkillID WHERE ESB.SkillID = " + TextBox1.Text ;
}
else
{
    strcommand = "SELECT * FROM Emp_Skill_Bridge ESB INNER JOIN  Emp E " + 
                 "ON E.EmpId = ESB.EmpId INNER JOIN  Skills S ON " +
                 "S.SkillID = ESB.SkillID WHERE ESB.SkillName  like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" ;

}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcommand ,con);
```

Comment: Well, the above method which I tried is working but not populating in my GridView1 control..

Comment: then better check whether DataSet is not empty.
    **da.Fill(ds);**

Comment: @Girish , you better remove **GridView1.DataSourceID = null;** once and try to run the code.

Comment: Oh, I found out the problem.. Well, I still need to type in as "numeric" in the textbox field.. Example "2".. then it will pull up all the info about Employee from Emp.. How'd I do in such a way I can type "Java" and search?

Comment: @Girish , are you typing "2" including the double quotes ?
 what is the result you are getting when you are typing **java** or **.net** in the textbox.

Comment: No I just typed 2 (Because skillID is 2 for Java).. And when I type Java, it just gets refresh but no value is shown nor any error appears..

Comment: @Girish , you better use break point and debug the code, see whats the value of **strcommand** , copy it to sql server and execute there once.

Comment: @mourya.. Thanks for help and suggestions :) I found out the mistake. It was in SQL query tht- ` WHERE ESB.SkillID LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' OR **S.SkillName** LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";`